# Thrown out of app when going to a certain activity

Tags: android

When pressing the menu button to go to the activity Settings (java code below), I'm thrown out of the app.

However, when I delete the **setOnClickListener section**, the app goes to Settings without any problem.

The purpose of the Settings activity is quite simple: allowing the user to enter a name (for a game player).

Any idea what could cause this?

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Settings extends MainActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);

        namePlayer1 = findViewById(R.id.editPlayer1);

        submitNamesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                player_A = namePlayer1.getText().toString();
                packageButtonMethods();
            }
        });

    }

    TextView namePlayer1;
    Button submitNamesButton;
```

No error messages during compiling. Just been thrown out of the app. I test run the app on a real smartphone.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forgot to initialize the button and it produces a NullPointerException